# How to access sqlite3 database using NodeJS from another Docker container?

Tags: node.js, docker

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  pa-portal:
    image: web_app_image
    container_name: pa-portal
    volumes:
      - productDB:/web_app/db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:4.4.0"
    depends_on:
      - pa-portal
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://pa-portal:8080
    working_dir: /cypress-testing

    volumes:
      - ./:/cypress-testing

volumes:
  productDB:
```

In one of my Cypress tasks I have the following snippet of code:

```
  let db = new sqlite3.Database('pa-portal:8080/web_app/db/db.sqlite3', sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the database.');
  });


  db.run(`DELETE FROM table_name`, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log(`Row(s) deleted ${this.changes}`);});
```

but I am getting the message that

```
 Connected to the database.
cypress_1    | SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file
```

I am guessing I am accessing the database in the wrong way, and I need a Docker specific way of doing it...

Comment: It's probably easier to use a server-based database like PostgreSQL.  Then you can connect to that database using ordinary Docker networking, and you won't have trouble if you eventually move to a multi-host installation like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.

Comment: @DavidMaze That db.sqlite3 file is part of someone else's Django web app, surely I should just be able to access a file from another container on the same network

Comment: No, Docker doesn't work that way.  Containers' filesystems are isolated from each other and the host.

Answer (score 1):

> That db.sqlite3 file is part of someone else's Django web app

Then that Django app should be exposing an API to prevent unauthorized access to that Database.

As mentioned, container filesystems are isolated from one another

Comment: How is it possible to make an API request to a database file?

Comment: Nope. Files don't expose APIs. Especially not over network boundaries